# Riesz representation for products?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, distribution-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Given is a continuous linear functional $T:C_c^0(\mathbb{R})\otimes C_c^0(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $C_c^0(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of continuos functions with compact support. Since $C_c^0(\mathbb{R})\otimes C_c^0(\mathbb{R}) \cong C_c^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ via the Riesz representation theorem i can find a Radon measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$$T(\psi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\psi(x)\nu(dx) \; \; \;  \forall \psi \in C_c^0(\mathbb{R}^2) $$

where here $T$ is understood to be a continuous linear functional from $C_c^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it true then that for $T:C_c^0(\mathbb{R})\otimes C_c^0(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ there exists a Radon measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$T(\phi_1 \otimes \phi_2)=\int_\mathbb{R}\phi_1(\xi)\phi_2(\xi)\mu(d\xi) \; \; \; \forall \phi_1,\phi_2 \in C_c^0(\mathbb{R}) ?$$

Comment: What is the topology on $C^\infty_c$? Are you sure you didn't mean $C^0_c$?

Comment: In this case I'm interested in the case of infinitely differentiable functions so the correct notation should be $C_c^\infty$. To have an idea: the topology is defined as an inductive limit topology of topologies defined by the collection of seminorms $||f||_{\alpha,K}:=\sup_{x \in K}|D^\alpha f(x)|$ when $K$ is a compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha$ is a multi-index $|\alpha|\leq k$. Then one is regarded of induced topologies on subspaces of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yeah, ok, but if you consider $C^\infty_c$, there are MANY more continuous functionals than just Radon measures. You have ALL distributions. For example, derivatives of the Dirac delta are continuous functionals on $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ (with the topology you recalled).

Comment: I'm passing through Riesz representation. Can't see what's wrong with that..

Comment: Riesz representation is about the space of **continuous** functions. Here you took $C^\infty_c$ functions. In the end, the answer of Adriàn will be OK, but be aware that your continuous functionals are not necessarily measures, they can be arbitrary distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll take it into account ;)

Comment: So, in this question, when you say: "via the Riesz representation theorem I can find a Radon measure $\nu$", it is WRONG. Either you say that $\nu$ is a distribution, or you change your space and you take $C^0_c$ instead of $C^\infty_c$.

Comment: yes of course, I'll change it, even though I was interested in the case of functionals in $C_c^\infty$ that admits the representation as an integral of measures. But those are exactly those that operates in $C_c^0$. ty!

Comment: Pleasure. Glad it helped. Thank you for modifying the question! You removed the only obstruction that prevented me from upvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement the answer above: There are several subtleties that you are missing.

1. To justify the identity $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \otimes C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) = C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ you need to define [tensor products in the category of topological locally convex vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product). In that category there are several tensor products available (the projective and injective being the minimal and maximal objects). In the case of some very special spaces, called nuclear spaces both coincide. You are working with a [nuclear space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space#Examples).
2. You can identify the space of bi-continuous bilinear forms $B: X \times Y \to \mathbb{C}$ with the dual of the projective tensor product of $X$ and $Y$. I.e:
   $$
     B_{bi}(X \times Y \to \mathbb{C})
     = (X \otimes_{\pi} Y)^\ast,
   $$
   where $\otimes_\pi$ is the projective tensor product- In your case $X = Y = C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and so $X \otimes_\pi Y = C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$. It dual is the space of (non tempered) distribution over $\mathbb{R}^2$
3. What you are really asking is which bilinear forms $B: C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \times C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{C}$ **factor through** the multiplication map. I.e. there is a $T: C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $B = T \circ m$, where $m: C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \times C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \to C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the multiplication. Those forms are the ones with [support inside the diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Support_of_a_distribution).

Comment: Dear @adrián-gonzález-pérez, this was exactly what I had in mind as an answer. What I do not understand is "support inside the diagonal". Could you please be more specific and clarify this? ty

Comment: Given a distribution, there is a notion of its support. Basically the largest closed set such that evaluating the distribution against a test function supported in the complement gives zero. If the support is a set and the bilinear forms are $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)'$, you can define the support of your form as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: so those forms are really very few w.r.t. distributions on $\mathbb{R}^2$, just the ones with support on the diagonal, ok! Really clear, ty!

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. For example, let $T = \delta_x \otimes \delta_y$ where $x \neq y$ so that
$$T(\phi \otimes \psi) := \phi(x) \psi(y)$$
Since $x \neq y$, we can find $\phi_x$ and $\phi_y$ with disjoint support such that $\phi_x(x) = 1$ and $\phi_y(y) = 1$. This implies that for any Radon measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_x(\xi) \phi_y(\xi) \mu(d \xi) = 0$$
but 
$$T(\phi_x \otimes \phi_y) = \phi_x(x) \phi_y(y) = 1$$